# Dynamic JSON remapping

Tags: java, json, dynamic-controls

I need to make my JSON API output editable dynamically through mapping some values in it to new keys (dynamically) 
for example:

API Output:

```
{
    "ABC": {
        "a": "Key1",
        "b": [
            1,
            2,
            3
        ],
        "c": {
            "c1": 4,
            "c2": 5
        }
    }
}
```

output willing to have:

```
{
    "e":"key1,chooses ABC.a",
    "f":"1 chooses ABC.b[0]",
    "g":"4 chooses ABC.c.c1"
}
```

NB: e,f, and g are key the I predefined already for this mapping purpose.

I tried scooping JOLT and similar tools but they didn't fit.

Comment: Can you please provide at least an attempt of your solution? Are a b c always formatted like this?

Comment: a,b, and c are dummy unknown keys returned from the API, what I care about is the value of those keys, not the keys. check output willing to have section in my question for the example

Comment: what I need to have is the ability to refactor the json the way i want dynamically